# UIWebView not opening requested url from other view controller Objective C

Tags: objective-c, url, uiwebview, controller

### mainViewController.h

```
#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"
-(void)Loadwebview:(NSURL *)url;
```

### mainViewController.m

```
-(void)Loadwebview:(NSURL *)url
{
   // NSURL *testURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSLog(@"loadwebview: %@", url);
    [webViewBox loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}
```

### leftViewController.h

```
#import "mainViewController.h"
#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"
```

### leftViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *urlString = [[dao libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"url"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]; //urlString];

    NSLog(@"selected url: %@", url);

    mainViewController *mvc = [[mainViewController alloc]init];
    [mvc Loadwebview:url];  

    //NSLog(@"%@", [[dao libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"url"]);

    [self.slidingViewController resetTopView]; //it will show mainViewController 

}
```

This code is not working... OutPut steps are,
Log shows :

> Selected url: http://www.google.com
>
> loadwebview: http://www.google.com

which means I am passing url from `leftViewController.m` to `mainViewController.m` and calling `loadwebview` function properly. But the issue is that `webViewBox` is not opening requested url.
:-(

Comment: How you are initializing webViewBox?

Comment: <UIWebViewDelegate> @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webViewBox;
and connected UIWebView Delegate to the fileowner

Comment: Have you connected outlets properly? if yes then check it is loading or not by adding these delegate methods.- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error;

Comment: yes everything is fine except the defined issue.. I have textfield to open url in webViewBox and it is working. I am using activity indicator to stop when webViewDidFinishedLoad. all works with textfield. loadwebview function works when i call it from the same view controller. but not work when i call from other view controller.

Comment: Sorry about asking question here, but I have the same question now and can't find solution... do you finally found some way to make webview working?

Comment: no.. didnt found the solution :-(